# logical statement: proving $\mathrm{len}(\psi)\leq4\cdot\mathrm{lenz}(\psi)+1$

Tags: logic

Given a logical statement $\psi$ I want to prove $\mathrm{len}(\psi)\leq4\cdot\mathrm{lenz}(\psi)+1$

with $\mathrm{lenz}:=\textrm{number of all logical connectives}$ and $\mathrm{len:=\textrm{number of all signs}}$ of the logical statement.

So I want to use the induction.

If $\psi\equiv A$  with a statement $A$ the inequality is obvious. But now I am stuck. 
So how can you do the induction step for proving the formula above?

Comment: It depends on your definition of a well-formed statement. If $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are statements, what parentheses does your definition require in constructing $\varphi\lor\psi$, for instance?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I was asking for. And I expect that for negation you get $(\neg\varphi)$, yes?

Comment: The question and the accepted answer depend on unspecified definitions. I guess this is a homework question. The question and answer are useless to anyone who doesn't know the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{\land,\lnot,\forall\}$ is an adequate set of connectives, it suffices to show it for these. I will assume the parentheses are as $(\varphi\land\psi)$, $(\lnot\varphi)$ and $(\forall x)\varphi$. Assume it holds for $\varphi$, $\psi$. Then for $\land$ we have

$$len[(\varphi\land\psi)]=len[\varphi]+len[\psi]+3\leq 4(lenz[\varphi]+lenz[\psi])+5\\=4(lenz[(\varphi\land\psi)]-1)+5=4(lenz[(\varphi\land\psi)]+1,$$

for $\lnot$ we have

$$len[(\lnot\varphi)]=len[\varphi]+3\leq 4lenz[\varphi]+4=4(lenz[(\lnot\varphi)]-1)+4=4lenz[(\lnot\varphi)]$$

and finally for $\forall$:

$$len[(\forall x)\varphi]=len[\varphi]+4\leq 4lenz[\varphi]+5=4(lenz[(\forall x)\varphi]-1)+5=4lenz[(\forall x)\varphi]+1.$$